# Can a synchronized method of an instance be locked by synchronized statement

Tags: java, multithreading

I have run into a code piece in official tutorial of concurrency :

```
public SynchronizedRGB(int red,
                           int green,
                           int blue,
                           String name) {
        check(red, green, blue);
        this.red = red;
        this.green = green;
        this.blue = blue;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void set(int red,
                    int green,
                    int blue,
                    String name) {
        check(red, green, blue);
        synchronized (this) {
            this.red = red;
            this.green = green;
            this.blue = blue;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public synchronized int getRGB() {
        return ((red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue);
    }

    public synchronized String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public synchronized void invert() {
        red = 255 - red;
        green = 255 - green;
        blue = 255 - blue;
        name = "Inverse of " + name;
    }
}
```

My question is :

If a thread uses `set` method, can another thread use one of the synchronized methods, or the other way around ?

Comment: no, that's what `synchronized` does.

Comment: It actually depends **where** in the method you are. While `set()` executes synchronized content, other methods will be blocked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they can't. At least not while you are inside the `synchronized(this)` block.
Declaring a non-static method as `synchronized` has the same effect as putting everything inside the method into a `synchronized(this) {}` block.

Thus, while one thread is inside a non-static method declared as `synchronized`, no other thread may execute either a `synchronized` method or a `synchronized(this) {}` block.

For methods declared as `static` in the class `ThisClass`: They are handled the same way as if the contents of the method was inside a `synchronized(ThisClass.class) {}` block.

---

For your example, if you wonder why this does not work correctly:

```
SynchronizedRGB color = new SynchronizedRGB(0, 0, 0, "Pitch Black");
...
int myColorInt = color.getRGB();      //Statement 1
String myColorName = color.getName(); //Statement 2
```

`getRGB()` and `getName()` do lock on `this`. *But* between the two method calls the lock is released again so that another thread could acquire it, then release it, and only then the first thread could finally execute `getName()`. Thus another thread could change the color between the the `RGB` and the `Name` getter so the name and RGB returned would not fit to the same color.

If you do it like this:

```
SynchronizedRGB color = new SynchronizedRGB(0, 0, 0, "Pitch Black");
...
synchronized(color) {
    int myColorInt = color.getRGB();      //Statement 1
    String myColorName = color.getName(); //Statement 2
}
```

In this case the lock on the object is not released between `getRGB()` and `getName()` so that no thread could acquire it at this time.

Answer (score 0):

No; `synchronized` methods will synchronize on `this`.

Also, this is poor code; the entire class should be immutable, solving all threading problems without synchronization.

Comment: It is what the tutorial is teaching. But I dont understand. The tutorial says that it can ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncrgb.html

Comment: What don't you understand? A synchronized method cannot run while another thread is in a `synchronized(this)` block.

Comment: Read the official tutorial, it says, it can because  there is a memory inconsistency issue according to what it says, that is why i am asking the question dont u think ?